# C++11 Multiple move constructor call

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I've compiled this with `g++ -std=c++11 file.cpp` and I am quite confused by studying the move constructor in `C++`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class P {
public:
    string* ptr_;
    P(string name) { ptr_ = new string(name); }
    ~P() { delete ptr_; }
    P(P&& pother) : ptr_(move(pother.ptr_)) { 
        cout<<"move"<<endl; 
        pother.ptr_=nullptr; 
    }
    void print() {cout << *ptr_ << endl;}
};

int main()
{
    vector<P> ppl;
    ppl.push_back(P("Jojo"));
    ppl.push_back(P("Jojo"));
    ppl.push_back(P("Jojo"));
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
$ ./a.out 
move
move
move
move
move
move
```

Why is the move constructor called 6 times here?

Comment: Print out the capacity and size of the vector before and after each call to `push_back` and it should shed some light on the subject.

Comment: The `ptr_(move(pother.ptr_))` won't actually "move" anything, since it is a pointer.  Can be a `ptr_(pother.ptr_)`.  It's not wrong, but a pointer or an int or any of the basic types just isn't what a makes a universal reference interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) causes reallocation; when the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` `vector` allocates new underlying storage and all the current elements are moved to new storage via move constructor. The moving of elements during reallocation cause these multiple invocations of move constructor.

How capacity grows is not explicitly specified by standard; I suppose it's doubled for every reallocation here, then

```
ppl.push_back(P("Jojo")); // 0 element(s) moved, 1 element added, 1 move(s) in all; size=1, capacity=1
ppl.push_back(P("Jojo")); // 1 element(s) moved, 1 element added, 2 move(s) in all; size=2, capacity=2
ppl.push_back(P("Jojo")); // 2 element(s) moved, 1 element added, 3 move(s) in all; size=3, capacity=4

// assume the 4th push_back is performed
ppl.push_back(P("Jojo")); // 0 element(s) moved, 1 element added, 1 move(s) in all; size=4, capacity=4
```

So the move constructor is invoked 6 times. BTW if you perform `push_back` one more time, only one time move constructor will be invoked; because for the 4th `push_back` no reallocation happens.

You can use [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to avoid reallocation.

```
vector<P> ppl;
ppl.reserve(3); // prohibit reallocations for the following 3 push_back
ppl.push_back(P("Jojo"));
ppl.push_back(P("Jojo"));
ppl.push_back(P("Jojo"));
```

Comment: Why is this well-formed even though his move constructor is not `noexcept`?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Because there's no copy constructor? I failed to confirm in the standard whether it's mandatory that move constructor must be `noexcept` or there must be available copy constructor for reallocation.